# Java WebStart does not see the parameters in the first run

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I need to pass a dynamically generated parameter (a token) to the web start app. The problem is that unless the application was previously cached by the JWS, the parameter is not getting passed. I have tried passing it like this:

```
 <property name="token" value="a3ftBH5vfTZurTzUl378"/>
```

and retrieving using the  `System.getProperty("token");` as well as passing the main function arguments

```
<application-desc main-class="com.xxx.MainClass">
    <argument>-token a3ftBH5vfTZurTzUl378</argument>
</application-desc>
```

The same result. Clean cache -> first run -> token=null. Second run -> token=a3ftBH5vfTZurTzUl378

I know that such behavior is documented as normal regarding the splash screen shown during the start of the JWS apps, but is it the same for the parameters? This seems completely unacceptable to me. Any advice to circumvent this would be appreciated.

Comment: Validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) (for both properties and run-time args).  Strictly speaking the `<argument>` should be split in two parts, unless you are splitting it on space at run-time. If that does not fix the problem, have a look in the bug DB, and raise a new one if none found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you specify as codebase and href in the top  element?

The first run may use the downloaded jnlp directly while the second run downloads whatever is specified there. This may result in different behaviour it these files are not consistent.

Comment: as far as I remember this was exactly the problem that my jnlp file had. It is already fixed, but thanks for the answer, anyhow.